# Javascript array of objects potential data structure issue when cleaning data

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to clean an array of objects I parsed from a text file with Javascript. Through a combination of help from SO, my Google-fu, and a long time of tinkering, I was able to remove all null values, remove extra characters from the amount values, trim extra whitespace from the amount and description values, and convert the amount values to integers. All of this works fine on the Plunker link below.

```
var transferArray = [{
    "transferCode": [
      "23100"
    ],
    "details": [
      {
        "voucherNumber": [
          "0000047381",
          "0000047427",
          "0000047480",
          "0000047494",
          "0000047508",
          "0000047516",
          "0000047597",
          "0000047608",
          "0000047631",
          "0000047646",
          "0000047670",
          "0000047675",
          "0000047695"
        ],
        "vendor": [
          "Central Equatoria State",
          "EASTERN EQUATORIA ST",
          "JONGLEI STATE",
          "Lakes State",
          "Northern Bahr-el State",
          "Unity State",
          "Northern Bahr-el State",
          "Western E State",
          "Warap State",
          "Greater Pibor Admin.Area",
          "Upper Nile State",
          "Western BG State"
        ],
        "description": [
          "1003-1500 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1501 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1503 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1504 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1505 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1506 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1505 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1508 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1511 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-0926 Block Grant Sep                  ",
          "1003-1507 Block Grant Oct                  ",
          "1003-1509 Block Grant Oct                  3,178,342.00\"\r            "
        ],
        "amount": [
          "t                  6,027,922.00",
          "t                  5,510,965.00",
          "t                  5,280,181.00",
          "t                  4,814,009.00",
          "t                  3,826,046.00",
          "t                  4,672,368.00",
          "t                  1,200,000.00",
          "t                   4,509,358.00",
          "t                  5,547,404.00",
          "t                  2,462,988.00",
          "p                  3,067,645.00",
          "t                  5,663,401.00",
          "t                  3,178,342.00"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "transferCode": [
      "23201"
    ],
    "details": [
      {
        "voucherNumber": [
          "0000047585",
          "0000047589",
          "0000047601",
          "0000047602",
          "0000047604",
          "0000047674",
          "0000047690",
          "0000047697",
          "0000047725"
        ],
        "vendor": [
          "Central Equatoria State",
          "EASTERN EQUATORIA ST",
          "Northern Bahr-el State",
          "Unity State",
          "JONGLEI STATE",
          "Western E State",
          "Warap State",
          "Upper Nile State",
          "Western BG State"
        ],
        "description": [
          "1003-1552 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
          "1003-1553 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
          "1003-0048 Sal Tax Adj Gran Jul               ",
          "1003-1557 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep               ",
          "1003-1554 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
          "1003-1561 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep               ",
          "1003-1559 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
          "1003-1558 Sal Tax Adj Gran Oct             ",
          "1003-1560 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             1,375,683.00\"\r            "
        ],
        "amount": [
          "p             9,039,784.00",
          "p             3,774,442.00",
          "l               741,962.00",
          "p               890,633.00",
          "p             3,968,445.00",
          "p               996,638.00",
          "p             1,779,481.00",
          "t             3,102,814.00",
          "p             1,375,683.00"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]

function removeNulls(obj) {
  var isArray = obj instanceof Array;
  for(var k in obj) {
    if(obj[k] === null) isArray ? obj.splice(k, 1) : delete obj[k];
    else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") removeNulls(obj[k]);
  }
}

removeNulls(transferArray);

console.log(JSON.stringify(transferArray, null, 2))

var cleanData = transferArray.map(function(e) {
                cleanData = e.details.map(function(evt, err) {
                    for(i = 0; i < evt.amount.length; i++) {
                        evt.amount[i] = evt.amount[i].toString();
                        evt.amount[i] = evt.amount[i].replace(/^[a-zA-Z]\s+/g, '');
                    evt.amount[i] = parseFloat(evt.amount[i].replace(/\,/g, ""));
                    }
                    for(i = 0; i < evt.description.length; i++) {
                    evt.description[i] = evt.description[i].toString();
                    evt.description[i] = evt.description[i].trim();
                    }
                    return(evt)
            })
            return(e)
            // console.log(evt.amount);
            // console.log(evt.description);
});

console.log(transferArray);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fy1jlV7KdNhWoPqvw4ng?p=preview

Unfortunately, when I try to incorporate that into my code, which has a larger array of objects of the same structure, it does not work. The null and undefined values are removed, but the cleanData function does not appear to work properly.

I have a suspicion that my data structure in reality is different from the Plunker, but I can't really see the difference. I provided a screenshot below:

[image: screenshot of upload test]

I'd be grateful for any help or guidance. I've been trying to wrap my head around this one for a couple days now.

**EDIT:**

I updated the plunker and the code here with a sample of the actual data structure, as it differed slightly from the example I previously provided.

Comment: You want to clear out `null`s in the amount array right?

Comment: Yeah, that bit is working fine. It's the cleanData function that's not working. I threw a few debuggers in there and it hits everything, just doesn't return what I need, which is amount w/o the first character, trimmed, and turned into an integer, and description trimmed.

Comment: `.map()` returns an array of all the values returned by the function. But your function doesn't return anything.

Comment: There is no `cleanData` function, it's a variable that you assign to the result of calling `.map()`. Why do you use the same variable for the outer call and the inner call?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I misspoke. No reason really. I know it's bad practice, I just did it without thinking

Comment: Do you want to clean the data in place, or return a new array with the clean data?

Comment: I'd prefer it to be cleaned in the existing array if possible.

Comment: It looks like that's what it's doing. I checked your Plunker, and the second `console.log` shows that the data has been cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

This will clear out `null` quantities and convert quantities with numerical strings to numbers:

```js
var transferArray = [{
   "transferCode": 8675309,
       "details": [
          {
            "voucherNumber": [34, 21],
            "vendor": ["stan", "kyle"],
            "description": ["blah      ", "blah blah        "],
            "amount": ["t        45,555.00", "p         34,456.00"]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "transferCode": 45576543,
      "details": [
          {
            "voucherNumber": [22, 57],
            "vendor": ["Johnson", "Tyler"],
            "description": ["trap music      ", "The Wiz"],
            "amount": [null, "r       77,564.00"]
          }
        ]
    }];

var clean = transferArray.map(function(transfer){
  transfer.details = transfer.details.map(function(detail){
    detail.amount = detail.amount.filter(function(quantity){
      if(quantity !== null){
        return true;
      }
    });
    detail.amount = detail.amount.map(function(quantity){
      var num = quantity.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '');
      return Number(num);
    });
    return detail;
  });
  return transfer;
});

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(clean, null, '\t');
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Annoyingly, the .replace function is not working, as in my code quantity is an object, not a string.

Comment: `quantity` are elements of the `amount` array. In your `amount` array, there are no objects, only `string`s or `null`s. I filter outer the `null` values first, so unless there are objects we don't know about on the `amount` array, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `removeNulls` function has a bug. When it splices a null element out of an array, that shifts all the following elements down -- the next element gets the index of the one that you just deleted. As a result, you'll never test the element that was shifted into its place. You should generally use a `for` loop to iterate over arrays, not `for-in`. And if you're going to splice elements out, the way I recommend is to iterate in reverse order:

The problem with `cleanData` is that you're using `.map()`, but you're not returning anything from the callback function. You should just use `.forEach()`, which iterates over the array, it doesn't return anything. So there's no need to assign the result to a variable.

```js
var transferArray = [{
  "transferCode": [
    "23100"
  ],
  "details": [{
    "voucherNumber": [
      "0000047381",
      "0000047427",
      "0000047480",
      "0000047494",
      "0000047508",
      "0000047516",
      "0000047597",
      "0000047608",
      "0000047631",
      "0000047646",
      "0000047670",
      "0000047675",
      "0000047695"
    ],
    "vendor": [
      "Central Equatoria State",
      "EASTERN EQUATORIA ST",
      "JONGLEI STATE",
      "Lakes State",
      "Northern Bahr-el State",
      "Unity State",
      "Northern Bahr-el State",
      "Western E State",
      "Warap State",
      "Greater Pibor Admin.Area",
      "Upper Nile State",
      "Western BG State"
    ],
    "description": [
      "1003-1500 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1501 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1503 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1504 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1505 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1506 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1505 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1508 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1511 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-0926 Block Grant Sep                  ",
      "1003-1507 Block Grant Oct                  ",
      "1003-1509 Block Grant Oct                  3,178,342.00\"\r            "
    ],
    "amount": [
      "t                  6,027,922.00",
      "t                  5,510,965.00",
      "t                  5,280,181.00",
      "t                  4,814,009.00",
      "t                  3,826,046.00",
      "t                  4,672,368.00",
      "t                  1,200,000.00",
      "t                   4,509,358.00",
      "t                  5,547,404.00",
      "t                  2,462,988.00",
      "p                  3,067,645.00",
      "t                  5,663,401.00",
      "t                  3,178,342.00"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  "transferCode": [
    "23201"
  ],
  "details": [{
    "voucherNumber": [
      "0000047585",
      "0000047589",
      "0000047601",
      "0000047602",
      "0000047604",
      "0000047674",
      "0000047690",
      "0000047697",
      "0000047725"
    ],
    "vendor": [
      "Central Equatoria State",
      "EASTERN EQUATORIA ST",
      "Northern Bahr-el State",
      "Unity State",
      "JONGLEI STATE",
      "Western E State",
      "Warap State",
      "Upper Nile State",
      "Western BG State"
    ],
    "description": [
      "1003-1552 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
      "1003-1553 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
      "1003-0048 Sal Tax Adj Gran Jul               ",
      "1003-1557 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep               ",
      "1003-1554 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
      "1003-1561 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep               ",
      "1003-1559 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             ",
      "1003-1558 Sal Tax Adj Gran Oct             ",
      "1003-1560 Sal Tax Adj Gran Sep             1,375,683.00\"\r            "
    ],
    "amount": [
      "p             9,039,784.00",
      "p             3,774,442.00",
      "l               741,962.00",
      "p               890,633.00",
      "p             3,968,445.00",
      "p               996,638.00",
      "p             1,779,481.00",
      "t             3,102,814.00",
      "p             1,375,683.00"
    ]
  }]
}];

function removeNulls(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = obj.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (obj[i] === null) {
                obj.splice(i, 1);
            } else if (typeof(obj[i]) == "object") {
                removeNulls(obj[i]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for(var k in obj) {
            if(obj[k] === null) {
                delete obj[k];
            } else if (typeof(obj[k]) == "object") {
                removeNulls(obj[k]);
            }
        }
    }
}

removeNulls(transferArray);

console.log(JSON.stringify(transferArray, null, 2))

transferArray.forEach(function(e) {
   e.details.forEach(function(evt) {
        for(i = 0; i < evt.amount.length; i++) {
            evt.amount[i] = evt.amount[i].toString();
            evt.amount[i] = evt.amount[i].replace(/^[a-zA-Z]\s+/g, '');
            evt.amount[i] = parseFloat(evt.amount[i].replace(/\,/g, ""));
        }
        for(i = 0; i < evt.description.length; i++) {
            evt.description[i] = evt.description[i].toString();
            evt.description[i] = evt.description[i].trim();
        }
     })
 // console.log(evt.amount);
 // console.log(evt.description);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(transferArray, null, 2))
```

Comment: So, I think my data structure must be different from the example. I applied the code you wrote to mine, and I'm getting the same result as before. Oddly, I just noticed that before, each amount value was stored in an array, like:

amount: Array[1]
  0: Array[13]
    0:  "t     12,345.00"
    1: "t       45,678.00"
    etc

Whereas after running your code, and my previous code for that matter, amount looks like this:

amount: Array[1]
  0: "t    12,345.00, t       45,678.00"

I'm lost as to why the structure of the data would change like this.

Comment: That looks like `amount` is a 2-dimensional array. In your example, `amount` is an array of strings. You can use nested loops to go through a 2-d array.

Comment: If you update the question to show the correct data structure, I'll update the answer to show how to iterate through it.

Comment: Done! Thanks again for all the help! I hope the actual data structure will shed some light on the issue

Comment: `amount` is not a 2-dimensional array. This code should work correctly.

Comment: I just copied your data into my answer. When I run it, the result looks correct.

Comment: The `amount` array hasn't changed much other than it has extra elements.

Comment: But I don't see where you're getting `Array[1] 0: Array[13]` from. That means that `amount` is an array with 1 element in it, and that one element is another array with 13 strings in it. But in the data structure you posted, `amount` is an array with 13 strings in it.